# input fields blank and no text entry showing on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an iOS app that was created some time ago, and this has always worked absolutely fine - but recently some people have been reporting that all text input fields are blank, and they can type into the fields, but no text shows while they are typing.

This seems to be random. I have seen the issue on iPad and iPhone, iOS 16 and iOS 15.

Here is a photo showing two iPhones side by side, both running iOS 15 - you can see one has text fields populated with placeholder text, the other shows blank. Both phones are running the exact same version of the app.

[image]

I have never seen this type of issue before.

I have also uploaded a full video showing what happens when you try to enter text into any text fields on a device that shows the issue here [no visible text being typed](https://www.eighteenthree.com/ios.mov)

On devices that have this issue, I have done a full hard reset, deleted and reinstalled the app, but still the same.

Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video in the link, the phone looks like the "Dark Mode" mode is turned on (this is how it can be seen on the keyboard), but the application seems to "respond" only to the color of the text (which becomes white)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this behavior a few weeks ago. Basically, in your application's **Info.plist** you can just force the app to use light mode. That way even if the user has dark mode turned on, when they type in the provided text field, the text will still appear.

I did this in objective c (there should be an equivalent way to do it in Swift) but in the **Info.plist** file you'll want add the following key

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Note: "Light" is case sensitive. I tried it with lowercase and though it compiles and works in simulation and TestFlight, when you push it to the App Store it gets flag.